# Android listed crypto algorithm not provided

Tags: java, android, security, openssl, bouncycastle

I'm trying to encrypt something in android so I have a method that
lists all the security providers and their algorithms, but when I go
to use one of the listed algorithms (ECDH in my case) it gives me:
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Provider AndroidOpenSSL does not provide EC. Both OpenSSL and BouncyCastle supposedly have an implementation
but when I try to use ECDH for with either provider it gives me the same 
exception. Any Ideas?

Comment: You need to post the code concerned.

Answer (score 1):

> ... but when I go to use one of the listed algorithms (ECDH in my case) it gives me: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Provider AndroidOpenSSL does not provide EC.

Correct. Down level versions of Android use OpenSSL 0.9.8 It lacks EC support.

Later versions of Android (circa Android 4) use OpenSSL 1.0.1. It provides EC support. See the AOSP sources at [android/platform/external/openssl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssl/).